# implement mysql with java or php

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, database

I know this might be stupid question but i am new here. I want to create a mysql database and implement it using java or php and attach the working database to a cd. the question is do you know guys know any online courses to help me learn how to implement mysql with java. and is php needed or only java and mysql needed. i have good knowledge about java but i am new to databases. i just know some sql and i used to use access to create database. my database needs to store info and enable different users to register and log in and order and my database should store what they order. i thought lynda course essential mysql with php but i am not sure if it is what i am looking for. sorry guys it is very stupid but i never used php or mysql and i am looking just for a starting point. thanks for help.

Comment: Google `JDBC MySQL tutorial` Just `Java SE` and `MySQL`.

Comment: Being new here, or at programming makes no difference. The biggest part of being a successful developer is knowing how to do your own research and figure out problems yourself. Posting to Stack Overflow is not Step 1 (or 2, or 3...)

Comment: Make sure you grab the latest version of `MySQL Workbench` as well.

Comment: Database Design, Database Administration, and Client/Server programming are all distinct subjects

Comment: you are right sir. Thanks for the advice, i really do regret for asking this stupid question. 
@JonathonReinhart

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the following links. Will be helpful for you.

[Java + Mysql sample->Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)

[Java + Mysql sample->vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)